# Import two Gif files together and play them with just one button

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing, import, gif-format

I have two gif files and I want to import and play them at the same time with just one play button. The target is to compare them easily. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite an ugly code, but it should do the job:

```
twogifs[X_, Y_] := (
  a = Import[X];
    b = Import[Y];
  ai = ImageDimensions[a[[1]]];
  b1 = ConstantArray[0, Length[b]];
  For[i = 1, i < Length[b] + 1, i++, 
   b1[[i]] = ImageResize[b[[i]], ai]];
  If[Length@a < Length@b1, 
   AppendTo[a, ConstantArray[a[[-1]], Length@b1 - Length@a]];
   a = Flatten@a, 
   If[Length@a > Length@b1, 
    AppendTo[b1, ConstantArray[b1[[-1]], Length@a - Length@b1]]];
   b1 = Flatten@b1];

  allImg = ImageAssemble[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ Transpose[{a, b1}];

  ListAnimate[allImg])
```

$\textbf{Edit}$

The function is edited and first resizes the gifs to be equal-sized and then makes them equal in number.

Comment: Don't worry about the ugliness. It works and that is fine. Thanks

Comment: I am facing one strange error for some pairs of gifs. It says "ImageAssemble::row: Expecting images of the same height in one row." Do you know how to deal with it?

Comment: Resize the images to a common height.